# Accessing User 'extended models' in Template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have extended my user model with a Profile model (housing pictures, information etc). I have done this as follows by defining the relationship in Profile as:

```
user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
```

Is it possible to pull this directly in my template without passing it from the view (via context) each time? Something like the following:

```
{{ request.user.profile.picture }}
```

(The above does not work for me)

As I want to use this in the base template, I don't want to pass it in every view.

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work"? Please elaborate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django puts `User` object into template context by default, which means you can access user like `{{ user }}`. Templates allow you to access related objects, so in order to get profile picture of a user, just do `{{ user.profile.picture }}`. If this returns nothing, make sure your user has a profile and profile's picture field is not empty.